# Show most recent topic in forum category with PHP MySQL JOINS

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently making a forum section in my website and I have a categories page that show the different categories that you can post in, in a table. One column of this table is a "Most recent topic" column. The table is made up of a while loop, running through each category in my categories database table. My issue is, the while loop keeps outputting EVERY topic and just reuses categories that it has already shown.
Here is the code:

```
$sql = "SELECT categories.cat_id, categories.cat_name, categories.cat_description, topics.topic_id, topics.topic_subject, topics.topic_date, topics.topic_cat FROM categories LEFT JOIN topics ON topics.topic_cat = categories.cat_id";
$query = $DB_con->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();

if (!$query) {
    echo 'No categories found.';
} else {
    echo '<table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Last Topic</th>
        </tr>';

    while($catRow = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>';
                echo '<h3><a href="category.php?id=' . $catRow['cat_id'] . '">' . $catRow['cat_name'] . '</a></h3>' . $catRow['cat_description'];
            echo '</td>';
            echo '<td>';                
                echo '<a href="topic.php?id=' . $catRow['topic_id'] . '">' . $catRow['topic_subject'] . '</a> on ' . substr($catRow['topic_date'],0,-8);
            echo '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';

}
?>
```

As I said before, the table keeps showing the same category multiple times, so that it can show me every topic that has been posted. I only want each category displayed once with the most recent topic in that category.

I hope somebody can help me. Let me know if it's not clear enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly your question, maybe you should change your query:

Updated:

```
SELECT categories.cat_id
    ,categories.cat_name
    ,categories.cat_description
        ,topics.topic_id
        ,topics.topic_subject
    ,T1.topic_date
    ,T1.topic_cat
FROM categories
LEFT JOIN (SELECT  topic_cat, MAX(topic_date) AS topic_date 
           FROM topics 
           GROUP BY topic_cat) AS T1 ON T1.topic_cat = categories.cat_id
LEFT JOIN topics ON T1.topic_cat = topics.topic_cat AND T1.topic_date=topics.topic_date
```

Comment: You know, I really thought this was going to work. The MAX(topic_date) felt like the right choice, but I'm still getting multiple iterations of each category with different topics in each.

Comment: Can you try updated version?  It would be easier to make tests if you post some sample data.